# url rewrite preserve get variables

Tags: .htaccess

**I am looking to rewrite**

```
http://domain.com/zzz-zzz/?source=[variable1]&referrer=[variable_2]
```

to

```
http://domain.com/xxx-xxx/?source=[variable1]&referrer=[variable_2]
```

**I had done :**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)zzz-zzz(.*)$
RewriteRule ^$ ?xxx-xxx%2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

The QUERY_STRING does not include the path and script file (zzz-zzz/). That would be the REQUEST_URI. The QUERY_STRING would be `source=variable1&referrer=variable2`. If all you want to do is change zzz-zzz to xxx-xxx:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule  ^zzz-zzz/?(.*)$  /xxx-xxx/$1  [R=301,L]
```

ought to get you close. The entire Query String should be brought over.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for help..can you please write full code

Comment: That's the whole thing. I just added the R=301 flag.

Comment: What happens? Does the URL shown in the browser address bar change at all? Do you get an error? Does your host allow you to do this kind of thing? You could try removing the RewriteBase line to see if it makes any difference. If you're still stuck, show your entire .htaccess file.